# MAT-files load slower the first time than the subsequent times

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I want to load a large set of MAT-files in a loop. I'm testing different ways to make the files load faster, and I have a subset of 10,000 files I'm working with, each containing about 50 variables of different sizes. I noticed an interesting detail:

1. If I load 10,000 files using `load(filename)` in a loop one after another, it takes about 5 minutes.
2. If I load the same set of files a few more times (basically repeat the test), the time doesn't change.
3. If I load only one variable from each file using `load(filename, 'varname')`, it takes about the same amount of time.
4. If I repeat step 3, it takes about **15 seconds** to complete the load. Same files, same variable being loaded.
5. If I now run step 1 and again repeat step 3, I'm back to the load taking about 5 minutes. But once I try to do a second load, it takes a very short time again.

I'm puzzled. Is Matlab somehow keeping the data in memory once it loads it from a file once? This phenomenon, however, survives Matlab restarts and `clear` commands, so can it actually be Windows 7 that's keeping a memory cache of some of the data?

Needless to say, I would like to determine what's causing the unexpected improvement and, if possible, reproduce it to make the first load as fast as the subsequent ones.

Comment: You are probably seeing a combination of Windows file-caching behaviour and Matlab memory-management behaviour.  If you were writing your own code in say java, I'd say run all 10000 files into one file.  And read it in in one go.

Comment: I doubt it's the Matlab memory management because the effect persists over a Matlab restart. I didn't think Windows was able to cache only parts of files (total size is around 10 Gb, too big to fit in memory at once).

Comment: 15 seconds is probably not enough time to open 10000 files and read 10Gig from the disk so perhaps the result in 4 is because Matlab can cache the 1 item from each file, but cannot cache 50 items from each file.